# Create a string array to hold divided tokens from a long string?

Tags: c, arrays

I have tried everything I know but I just can't create the array. Every time the terminal shows "Segmentation fault: 11". Please help, thanks!(details in my comments)

Updated: `char*load file(int *numberofwords)`returns reading from txt file(I made it up just to test how my program works):

> Have,a.nice day
>
> Bye.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


char *loadfile(int *counter) {
    int  i;
    char chr;
    char *data;
    char *junk;
    FILE *GENE;
    GENE = fopen("hw7codex.txt", "r");

    if (GENE == NULL) {
       printf("ERROR - Could not open file.\n");
       return NULL; 
    }


   while (1) {
      fscanf(GENE, "%s", junk);
      (*counter)++;
      if (feof(GENE)) break;
   }

   int wholecounter = 0;
   while (1) {
      fscanf(GENE, "%c", &chr);
      wholecounter++;
     if (feof(GENE)) break;
   }

   data = (char *)calloc(wholecounter, sizeof(char));
      if (data == NULL) {
        printf("ERROR - Could not allocate memory for the file.\n");
        return NULL;
   }

   rewind(GENE);
   i = 0;
   while (1) {
       fscanf(GENE, "%c", &chr);
       data[i++] = chr;
       if (feof(GENE)) break;
   }
   fclose(GENE);

   return data;
}






int main(void){

int wordscount=0;

char *temp;

//temp gets a long string from a txt file(which looks like
//"Have,a.nice day"then divides it to separate words:"Have","a", "nice","day"
temp = strtok(loadfile(&wordscount)," ,.\n"); 

//I want to know how many separate words in this txt file
printf("%s\n", loadfile(&wordscount));  //it prints out 5
printf("%d\n", wordscount);       //it prints out 'Have,a.nice day\nBye'


//I want to create a string array here to hold all those words , but I keep failing
char array[wordscount][40];

int j=0;
while (temp != NULL){
    strcpy(array[j], temp);
    j++;
    temp = strtok (NULL, " ,.\n");
    }


for (j = 0; j < wordscount; j++){
   printf("%s\n", array[j]);
    }
```

Comment: Where is the declaration of `array`?

Comment: you added a space in variable `words count`.

Comment: @jmstoker, that's the problem, I wrote something like `array[wordscount][40]` or `char *array; array = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char))` doesn't work. Terminal shows **Segmentation fault: 11**

Comment: also, you probably want to reserve space for your string, before you copy it there. maybe use `strdup()` instead. If you don't have it, define it. it's easy.

Comment: Add to your post the code for the array declaration you're using that gives the seg fault

Comment: use `char ** array;`, and dynamically allocate all your strings and the array itself. Use `realloc()` for that.

Comment: In order to define a static/auto array, use `char array[MAXSTRINGLENGTH][MAXSTRINGCOUNT]`.

Comment: @Deduplicator, I think it should be `char array[MAXSTRINGCOUNT][MAXSTRINGLENGTH]`? That doesn't work anyway

Comment: try it out, i so seldom use 2 dimensional static arrays...

Comment: First, initialize `j` to 0 before using it as the answer below says.

Comment: Your program crashes before `printf("%d\n", wordscount);` or after?

Comment: @jfly, after. As long as I try to declare `array`.

Comment: `char array[wordscount][40];` is illegal if your compiler don't support VLA. You need to declare an array of pointers, then allocate memory manually.

Comment: @jfly,thx! but I tried `char *array;`then `array = malloc(sizeof(char)*wordscount);`. It doesn't work

Comment: no, you **only** declare one pointer by `char *array`, see my answer.

Comment: Use `char**` as i said. One * too few. Also, `sizeof(char)` shows how green you are, forget about it fast: "How many char comprise a char?" Tautology is not concise.

Comment: It surprises me that no-one has asked to see the code for `loadfile()`.  I'd also be happier if you captured the return value from it into a variable, and then dumped the data it returns before doing anything else with it (such as shredding it with `strtok()`). I know what you say it contains, but you've not shown the data file nor exactly what it looks like when returned by `loadfile()`.

Answer (score 0):

`char array[wordscount][40];` is illegal if your compiler doesn't support VLA. You should declare an array of pointers that point to strings, then allocate memory manually:

```
char** array;
int i;
array = (char**)malloc(wordscount * sizeof(char*)); // 

for ( i = 0; i < wordscount; i++) {
    array[i] = (char*)malloc(40 * sizeof(char)); // make sure the length of every word is less than 40
};
```

**EDIT:**
if the `loadfile()` return what you write(don't know how you implement the `loadfile()`, you should allocate memory for the string in the function), and the `wordscount` is 5, then here is an example for you which works fine:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){

    int wordscount = 5;

    char *temp;
    char buf[128] = "Have,a.nice day\nBye";

    temp = strtok(buf, " ,.\n"); 

    char** array;
    int i;
    array = (char**)malloc(wordscount * sizeof(char*)); // 

    for ( i = 0; i < wordscount; i++) {
        array[i] = (char*)malloc(40 * sizeof(char)); // make sure the length of every word is less than 40
    }; 

    int j = 0;
    while (temp != NULL){
        strcpy(array[j], temp);
        j++;
        temp = strtok (NULL, " ,.\n");
    }

    for (j = 0; j < wordscount; j++){
        printf("%s\n", array[j]);
    }
}
```

In your `loadfile()`, `junk` is an uninitialized pointer, so this line: `fscanf(GENE, "%s", junk);` will cause undefined behavior.

Comment: Hm, don't remodel your code halfway. Do or don't do, there is no try, yoda spoke.

Comment: thank you but this only holds one word. What I want is to hold `words count` words

Comment: It does allocate space for `wordscount` words. Check the value of `wordscount` after the function `loadfile()`, and show us the string to be parsed.

Comment: print the return value of `loadfile()`, and the value of `wordscount`.

Comment: @jfly, I did print these 2

Comment: So what are they like?

Comment: `printf("%s\n", loadfile(&wordscount));`  //it prints out 5
`printf("%d\n", wordscount); `      //it prints out 'Have,a.nice day\nBye'

Comment: If so, I guess the `loadfile()` is the problem. You allocated the memory for the string to be parsed in the `loadfile()`? Edited the answer.

Comment: Your code sample is not correct, you declare an array of `40` pointers but then iterate up to `wordsCount`. If this count is over `40` then you have a buffer overflow.

Comment: @user3226666 In your loadfile(), `junk` is an uninitialized pointer, so this line: `fscanf(GENE, "%s", junk);` will cause undefined behavior. And the `counter` in it is not accurate.

Answer (score 0):

You `char *loadfile(int *counter)` seems buggy because you used   `while (1) {}` for reading file and break the loop by `if (feof(GENE)) break;` but `feof` it self buggy see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong)

Also you missed `rewind(GENE);` between first two `while..loop`. Add it.

So you can do as follows

```
   while (fscanf(GENE, "%s", junk)==1) // The scanf functions return the number of objects read.
   {
      (*counter)++;
   }
```

similar you apply for other loop.

This is the code error i captured form your `loadfile` function but still i don't know what you  expect from return value of `loadfile` and what output you want?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define DELIMITER " ,.\n"

const char *LoadFile = "data.txt";

char *loadfile(int *wc){
    FILE *fp = fopen(LoadFile, "r");
    if(!fp){
        perror("fopen");
        return NULL;
    }
    long fsize = 0;

    fseek(fp,0,SEEK_END);
    fsize = ftell(fp);//non portable
    fseek(fp,0,SEEK_SET);//reset stream position!!

    char *buff = malloc(fsize+1);
    if(!buff){
        perror("malloc");
        return NULL;
    }
    size_t rsize = fread(buff, sizeof(char), fsize, fp);
    fclose(fp);
    buff[rsize]='\0';

    int count = 0, pos = 0;//long ?
    while(1){
        int len = 0;
        sscanf(buff + pos, "%*[" DELIMITER "]%n", &len);
        pos += len;
        if(EOF!=sscanf(buff + pos, "%*[^" DELIMITER "]%n", &len)){
            pos +=len;
            ++count;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    *wc = count;
    return buff;
}

int main(void){
    int wordscount=0;
    char *buff, *temp;

    buff = loadfile(&wordscount);
    printf("%d\n", wordscount);  

    char array[wordscount][40];

    temp = strtok(buff, DELIMITER);
    int j;
    for(j = 0; temp != NULL; ++j){
        strcpy(array[j], temp);
        temp = strtok (NULL, DELIMITER);
    }
    free(buff);
    for (j = 0; j < wordscount; j++){
        printf("%s\n", array[j]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```